# Wildcards: Talking about "Object" vs "?"

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

Look at this two examples:

```
void printCollection(Collection<Object> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

vs

```
void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

What is the difference between these two? I read that the second example is more powerful. But why is that? Which argument you can't pass to method 1, which you can pass to method 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics [aren't covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p). In other words, a `Collection<String>` is not a `Collection<Object>`, even though a `String` is an `Object`. With the first signature, I wouldn't be able print a `List<String>` for example.

Generic wildcards assist in the expression of covariance (as in your example) and contravariance. `Collection<?>` is short for `Collection<? extends Object>` and means "a collection of some specific, unknown type that is or extends `Object`". As a consequence, we wouldn't be able to add anything but `null` to such a collection since we couldn't guarantee the added object's type would be valid.

Here's an example that uses a wildcard to express contravariance:

```
void populateCollection(Collection<? super Integer> c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        c.add(i);
    }
}
```

I could pass a `Collection<Object>`, `Collection<Number>`, or `Collection<Integer>` into this method, since it's treated as a *consumer* of `Integer`s. In your example, the collection is a *producer* of `Object`s. See this post for further reading on the distinction between "producers" and "consumers" with respect to wildcarded generic types: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)